# Want to execute code on listbox.items.clear()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a listbox and a checkbox(select all), In my code I'm calling `listbox.items.clear()`, now I want to subscribe to this event, so whenever my list box gets clear, the selectAll check box should also be in uncheck state.

Currently I am handling this in my listbox SelectedIndexChanged event, I could not find an ItemsClear kind of event in the list of my listbox events.

I would really like to uncheck my checkbox using event handling.

Comment: nothing to do much.. you can go for items.count if count is ==0 you can do whatever you want to do is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no event that is raised as a **direct** result of `ListBox.Items.Clear` being called. You can implement your own behavior though:

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    public event EventHandler ItemsCleared;

    public void ClearItems()
    {
        Items.Clear();
        if(this.ItemsCleared != null)
        {
            this.ItemsCleared(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Simply declare the class above in your Windows Forms Application. Instead of using the standard `ListBox` use your extended `CustomListBox` and subscribe to the `ItemsCleared` event.

Instead of calling `CustomListBox.Items.Clear` call `CustomListBox.ClearItems`

Comment: Okay as an idea, but overkill for this purpose I guess ;)

Comment: Personally I would consider a different approach however I'm responding to "I would really like to uncheck my checkbox using event handling."

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a round-trip. When you call your `Clear` method, you know that you are clearing it in the code. React in code, there is no need for the round trip.

For example create a helper method that clears the listbox and then executes the code you want after clearing the listbox.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there is no event for this. But why be so complicated? Define yourself a method like

```
private void ClearAndUncheck(){
    listbox.Items.Clear();
    selectAll.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If events are critical to you, I suggest to use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and bind the `ListBox` to, if your scenario allows it. This approach might give you some new ideas.

```
BindingList<string> myList;

myList = new BindingList<string>(...);
listBox1.DataSource = myList;
myList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(myList_ListChanged);
```

Then, by using the `ListChanged` event of the BindingList (among many others), you can do the operation on your "Select all" checkbox when your ListBox is cleared by `ListBox1.Items.Clear().`

```
void myList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset)
    {
        ... // Do what you need here
    }
}
```